# Unable to edit recode in cake php when I load the value in select box using j-query

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I am unable to load select box value when I want to update the value. The same code perfectly working when I am going to save value.

My controller code is:

```
public function listwardByCircle($category = "") {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->beforeRender();
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $ward=$this->Ward->find('list',array(
                "fields" => 'id, wardname',
                "conditions" => array('Ward.circle_id' => $category)
        ));
        //$this->set('ward',$ward);
        print_r($ward);
        foreach($ward as $key => $val) {
            echo "<option value=$key>$val</option>";
        }
    }
```

And this is my js code :

```
$("#AreaCircleId").change(function() {
alert("testing....");
$.post('../Admins/listwardByCircle/' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
alert(  data);
$("#AreaWardId").empty().append(data);
}, 'html');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`In js file`
`Url in Controller Like`

```
`\../../Admins\/listwardByCircle`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your URL post location in the ajax from:

```
$.post('../Admins/listwardByCircle/'
```

to

```
$.post('/admins/listwardByCircle/'
```

This is if the controller name is admins.